# Height of empty inline element different in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: html, css

It looks like the height of an empty `display: inline` element is different in Chrome vs Firefox. Is this a bug or WAI (e.g. Chrome vs Firefox interpreting some spec differently)?

Additionally, is there a conventional way web developers resolve this?

```js
// Logs 0 in Chrome, non-0 in Firefox.
console.log(document.querySelector('bar').getBoundingClientRect().height);
```

```html
<foo>
  <bar></bar>
</foo>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76773035/why-does-flex-child-element-reserve-vertical-space-only-on-firefox is also the answer here.

Answer (score -2):

The amount of spaces or tabs used for indentation has an impact on Python. Combining tabs and spaces can also lead to problems. When making your selection, stick to a standard of four spaces for each degree of indentation.